# HAL_Delay() gets into infinite loop

Tags: keil, hal

I'm using Stm32f429 discovery and I got a problem about using HAL_Delay() in my blinking project.when my program want to execute HAL_Delay it stucks in infinite loop.but if I create my project using CubeMX and I copy my code there it works correctly.Whats the problem?
Here is my code:

```js
#include "stm32f4xx_hal.h"

int main()
{
 HAL_Init();
 __HAL_RCC_GPIOG_CLK_ENABLE();
 GPIO_InitTypeDef a;
 a.Pin = GPIO_PIN_13 | GPIO_PIN_14;
        a.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
 HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOG, &a);
 while(1)
 {
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOG, GPIO_PIN_14, GPIO_PIN_SET);
  HAL_Delay(100);
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOG, GPIO_PIN_14, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  HAL_Delay(100);
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

HAL_Delay relies on Systick by default. So make sure you have a correct configuration for Systick (including enabling the interrupt) and for the system clock.